# PHP GD imagefilledrectangle

Tags: php, gd

I have built a system that collects images as inputted by codes and collected from a database (Not important to my question), but basically it is used to recolour a range of images. The problem I have is the images I am trying to use are in greyscale but the wrong end of the greyscale!

Basically the images I have are white moving onto black. But imagefilledrectangle only allows RGB 127.5,127.5,127.5 to be the exact colour of choice and not white... How can I change this?

Here is my code if it helps:

```
function postimage(&$image, $dir, $name, $check, $override, $color)
{
    $temp = imagecreatefrompng("./images/imager/".$dir.$name.".png");
    imagelayereffect($temp, IMG_EFFECT_OVERLAY);
    if ($check == 0)
    {
        imagefilledrectangle($temp, 0, 0, 64, 110, imagecolorallocate($temp, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]));
    }
    else if ($check == 1)
    {
        if ($override == 0)
        {
            imagefilledrectangle($temp, 0, 0, 64, 110, imagecolorallocate($temp, 255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
    $black = imagecolorallocate($temp, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($temp, $black);
    imagecopymerge($image, $temp, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($temp), imagesy($temp), 100);
    imagedestroy($temp);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does happen id you looped 127.5,127.5,127.5 twice?!

Comment: How do you calculate `$color`?

Comment: @MathieuImbert $color is just a RGB taken from the database, I have 1-1400 and all hold a different RBG. The problem is the source images are not in the correct greyscale, I'm trying to find out if it's possible to make 255,255,255 be the exact RGB chosen instead of 127,127,127 being the exact colour.

Comment: @SaidBakr Do you mean make the white image coloured 127.5,127.5,127.5 then colour it to my colour?

Comment: @SaidBakr Unfortunately that doesn't work, since the white in the image stays white as it's too far down the scale to be edited! So the image doesn't change at all.